# Every Time Require new Port Number in ReactJs Local Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am a beginner in ReactJS and I was working on a project and notice a strange thing happened to me every time.

Whenever I shutdown my local server and returned after some time to relaunch the app in the browser by `npm start`. It doesn't relaunch the app every time I have to give a new port number.
I am sure this is not the right behavior, I'm sure I am doing something wrong.

The error is shown every time in the start script which is below

```
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: watch /home/vidit/React/codevolution/public ENOSPC
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1382:19)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1408:11)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/vidit/React/codevolution/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:38:15)
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/vidit/React/codevolution/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:81:15)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/vidit/React/codevolution/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:233:14)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleDir (/home/vidit/React/codevolution/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:429:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/vidit/React/codevolution/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:477:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/vidit/React/codevolution/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:482:16)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:5)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! codevolution@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the codevolution@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vidit/.npm/_logs/2020-06-24T13_55_30_728Z-debug.log
vidit@PyPiper:~/React/codevolution$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error can be solved by two methods either we can specify some other PORT for doing so

You can make a `.env` file in the root and within this

```
PORT = <some port number> // PORT = 4001
```

or you can increase the limit by this

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

*Tested*

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting the file watch limit. There is a limit to how many files a process can watch.

Try this

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

Comment: maybe,  so you are trying to increase my limit to 524288 by this command ? is it.

Comment: Yes, the error stack trace shows chokidar, which is used by babel and webpack to monitor files

Comment: oh, So what exactly does this command do? As I can see it is accessing the config file. please explain to me. It will be helpful .

Comment: This [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444998/how-to-set-and-understand-fs-notify-max-user-watches) has a very simple explanation

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you still have processes from the old local server still hanging around and listening on those ports.

Make sure there is no serverprocess in taskmanager

Comment: No but there are no other processes running in the background or the PORT in busy

Comment: ok, run this in powershell:
    Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort portNumber).OwningProcess
where "portNumber" is the port you're unable to start on

Comment: so what I do every time in the `.env` file I assign a new Port number. and relaunch the server It works fine.